# Data functions in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, scramble

I want to scramble 2nd and 4th column of the data.

[1234567890] -> [8728125870]

Input:

```
 First_name,id,second_name,phone_number
 ram,232,prakash,96
 hari,123,pallavi,98
 anurag,456,aakash,13
```

Output Expected:

```
 First_name,id,second_name,phone_number
 ram,727,prakash,82
 hari,872,pallavi,78
 anurag,812,aakash,87
```

Comment: "Unix" isn't a programming language. How exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: Do you mean bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:

Generate a random number to be used for replacement.  This is done with something similar to `$(($RANDOM * 32768 + $RANDOM))`; if you need more details, let me know.

Step 2:

Use `tr` to replace all numbers with their "capital" versions, and replace them with the numbers you need.  So for your example, to replace just the 1, 2, and 3, you would run:

```
cat inputfile | tr '1' '!' | tr '2' '@' | tr '3' '#' | tr '4' '$' | tr '5' '%' | tr '6' '^' | tr '7' '&' | tr '9' '(' | tr '!' '8' | tr '@' '7' | tr '#' '2' | tr '$' '8' | tr '%' '1' | tr '^' '2' | tr '&' '5' | tr '(' '7'
```

Note: to get the effect you need, you would need to *extend* the command above for it to work.  Running it multiple times insted will produce the wrong results.

Output of the above command:

```
First_name,id,second_name,phone_number
 ram,727,prakash,96
 hari,872,pallavi,98
 anurag,456,aakash,87
```

Also: note how your "expected" output is not correct.  The first number should be 727, not 728.

Comment: hi Alex, Thanks for the answer. I dont want any randomised way. when ever i have 1234567890 numbers in my data thos have to scrambled into 8728125870 respectivly. Can you please try to give full length code.

Comment: OK, let me know if this does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    {
      cmd = "echo '" $0 "' | tr '1234567890' '8728125870'"
      new = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : $1 )
      close(cmd)
      split(new,tmp)
      for (i in tmp) {
          if (i ~ /^(2|4)$/) {
              $i = tmp[i]
                     }
     }
      print
   }
```

Save the above code in test.awk file and execute using -> awk -f test.awk datanew.csv